# Sparse matrix multiplication with CRS format

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, transpose

I am currently working with the multiplication of two sparse `A x B` which both are in the [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) format.
My current idea is that I transpose matrix `B` thus I can do a Matrix-Vector multiplication by taking the rows of both matrices which is an easy access in CRS format.
However I currently have my difficulties in transposing a matrix in the CRS format efficiently. Furthermore I am also curious if that is the most efficient algorithm or if I can multiply them without taking further action?

Comment: What programming language do you use? A hash table mapping matrix coordinates to nonzero values will give you the best possible (speaking strictly, amortized average asymptotic) time and memory complexity, i.e. linear in the number of nonzero values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotically_optimal_algorithm